# Playing silverlight video stream on osmc

Tags: streaming-video, osmc

I want to be able to watch television on my RPI2  running OSMC (Kodi). I thought of the following options:

**Web browser on Kodi**

Just opening the website on the Pi and play from there seemed the simplest solution. However, this will be less convenient with controls and furthermore, the site uses *Silverlight* to stream the content, which is to my understanding not easy to get working on a Pi.

**Streaming from laptop**

I found several plugins for casting video to kodi, but none of them seem to work with this silverlight implementation.

Casting the whole screen also seems to be infeasible, as noted for example [here](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=190069)

I found this [RPI-cast](https://github.com/andresromero/RPI-Cast) which starts the video's from command line using the python [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) package and the omxplayer and uses a chrome plugin. However, omxplayer does not seem to be practically useable on osmc. Furthermore, chrome does not seem to support silverlight.

Since there are no existing solutions I can find, what would be the best way to implement this? I have decent experience in Python programming, so I can write my own server implementation using Tornado and start video from command line somehow. But then I would still need to be able to grab the video stream from silverlight or the whole desktop to send to the tornado server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is "the site" that uses Silverlight? You are talking about watching TV on your RPi, which usually means plugging in a DVB or similar adapter into your computer to receive TV signals over the air or via COAX. Are you talking about a web-based rebroadcast of TV?

Comment: @PhilB. The site is from a dutch tv service [kpn](http://www.itvonline.nl). cable is not an option since it is already in use by two others  and a splitter to three is to expensive and impractical. Internet television is included in the subscription.

Comment: Welkom dan :) Have you looked at Pipelight or Moonlight? Both are Linux implementations of Silverlight ... not sure if the RPi's CPU is up to it though...

Comment: @PhilB. Thanks for your suggestion! That would, however, still require a browser. osmc does not (yet) have a default browser, and installing another browser via atp would require x11, as stated on the [forum](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/internet-browser/184/12). They are working on one, but I think for now that streaming would be a better option, but starting video from command line also seems hard